# How to fix "x and mean have non-conforming size"

Tags: r

I am trying to produce a contour plot of the overall fitted mixture distribution for a given set of data. My code is as follows:

```
mu1 <- matrix(c(0.2765799, 2.30699, 0.4268534, 2.6254749, -1.30049, -0.9883130), ncol = 3)

sigma1 <- matrix(c(0.9796896, -0.5666977, -0.5666977, 1.0509883), ncol = 2)

data.grid <- expand.grid(seq1 = seq(1,10, length.out = 200), seq2 = seq(0, 5, length.out = 200))

samp <- cbind(data.grid, prob = mvtnorm::dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = mu1, sigma = sigma1))

ggplot(samp, aes(x=seq1, y=seq2)) + geom_contour(samp, mapping = aes(x=seq1, y=seq2, z=prob)) + labs(x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width")
```

However, each time I try to run, I get an error saying:

> x and mean have non-conforming size

How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `ncol = 3` in `mu1` is correct? Try changing `mu1` as vector with length 2

Comment: yeah, it still has the same issue

Comment: `dmvnorm(data.grid, mean = c(1,2), sigma = sigma1)` works right. `mu` accept matrix as an input but I'm not sure about in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the documentation of `mvtnorm::dmvnorm`, you can see that the `mean` argument has to match the number of columns p in `x`, while the `sigma` argument is a covariance matrix of dimension [p,p].

Perhaps this is what you intended to do? This example uses the 3 indicated mean vectors (columns in `mu1`) as means (for iris species?), and always the same covariance matrix `sigma1`. Therefore, you will have three different means, but always the same multivariate spread in the resulting plot:

```
# matrix of means: 2x3
mu1 <- matrix(c(0.2765799, 2.30699, 0.4268534, 2.6254749, -1.30049, -0.9883130),
              ncol = 3) 

# covariance matrix: 2x2
sigma1 <- matrix(c(0.9796896, -0.5666977, -0.5666977, 1.0509883), ncol = 2)

# data.grid: 40000x2
data.grid <- expand.grid(seq1 = seq(-5,5, length.out = 200),
                         seq2 = seq(-5,5, length.out = 200))

# prob
probs <- sapply(1:ncol(mu1), function(x) {
  mvtnorm::dmvnorm(x = data.grid,
                 mean = mu1[,x], # length 2 vector 
                 sigma = sigma1)
})

# bind grid and probs
samp <- cbind(data.grid, 
              prob = probs)

# plot
ggplot(samp, aes(x=seq1, y=seq2)) + 
  geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.1), color = "tomato") + 
  geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.2), color = "darkblue") + 
  geom_contour(mapping = aes(z=prob.3), color = "green4") + 
  labs(x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

The trick is to re-use the `data.grid` for every multivariate normal density (one per species).

Note that if you provided different covariance matrices `sigma1` for each species, you could show different spreads. Also, I increased the data.grid range such that the mvnorm contours fit.

Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem lies in the different variables you use in `aes`.
You cannot just mix two different `aes` parametrizations in a single plot.

aes(x=seq1, y=seq2)
aes(x=seq1, y=seq2, **z=prob**)